# Why my custom delegate method does not receive the call?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I would like to send the message from HelloWorldLayer, and receive it in ScoreLayer, in order to update the label. The `CCLOG(@"///addNewScore");` works fine, but then `updateScore`, in ScoreLayer, does not receive the call, would you know why? Here's my code : (edit: i tried with "retain" in @property, but nothing changes) :

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer
{
    //...
    id<ScoreDelegate>delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) id <ScoreDelegate> delegate;


@implementation HelloWorldLayer
@synthesize delegate;
//...
-(void)addNewScore:(int)num{
    CCLOG(@"///addNewScore");//works fine
    [delegate updateScore:num];
}


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ScoreDelegate
-(void)updateScore:(int)num;
@end

@interface ScoreLayer : CCLayer <ScoreDelegate>{
    //...
}

-(void)updateScore:(int)num{
    CCLOG(@"hello");//DOES NOT WORK
}

@end
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You haven't shown where you are setting the `delegate` property of `HelloWorldLayer`.  I assume you are doing this somewhere?

Comment: @mttrb : sorry mttrb what do you mean? all the code about the delegate is above, am i missing something?

Comment: To clarify: the code we are looking for will look like this: `anHelloWorldLayer.delegate = aScoreLayer`, along with context, such as where this is occurring in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the ScoreLayer is being released before your call. I'm not too familiar with `assign`, I have only written ARC Objective-C; but I think it is roughly the same as weak (as it should be for delegates). This means that in order for that pointer to be valid, someone else in the application needs to "own" the ScoreLayer.

Now, that being said, I've only assumed that you are properly connecting the two objects in the first place. There isn't code posted which shows that, but this matter of a possibly-released ScoreLayer is important enough to keep in mind either way.

Comment: thanks ctrahey, i tried with `@property (nonatomic,retain)`, but no change. The delegate takes care of the retain thing doesn't it?

Comment: There is nowhere in your code where I can ascertain much of anything about how ScoreLayer is handled. Based on your response to @mttrb above, it seems like you are missing a critical piece of the puzzle: nothing is actually *giving* a ScoreLayer to a HelloWorldLayer.

Comment: oops you're right, it works now! thanks! can i ask you a last question? to update the score from 100 to 500 for example, i would like to show the numbers between 100 to 500, so that it does not go directly from 100 to 500, but 101, 102... 499,500 very quickly. But this blocks the ui for half a second, or more. Would you use a dispatchQueue only for that? thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: That's a great question for the SO community at large! I've got ideas, but others will certainly like to chime in. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Hexark, to which puzzle do you refer?

Comment: `if(delegate){[delegate delegateMethod]}` The delegate is nil. I do the exact same thing in another class, it works. But in this class it doesn't. I've no idea why..

Comment: 2 things: Make sure the delegate is being retained by someone (usually not you, be careful not to have any "children" point to their "parents" as delegates), and the more likely solution: step through your code and make *certain* that you are actually assigning your delegate somewhere (and that where you are assigning, you aren't inadvertently assigning nil).

Comment: I have 2 classes. One class `A` is doing many calculations, and the other class is `B` is displaying all the details. I am using delegate from class `A` to send data to class `B` to display data. Class `B` has some button which I want to trigger some delegate method upon pressed. While class `A` sending data to `B` works flawless, class `B` to `A` does not. Is this what u meant by children" point to their "parents? If so what solution is there?

Comment: If the general advice here does not lead you to the solution, open a new SO question and post your actual code so we can evaluate the specific difference :-)

Comment: ok Sorry. I thought because they were the same question. Thanks! :)

Comment: Same basic question, but if you can't find a solution based on what is here... ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You would declare that protocol (delegate method) in the interface file of `HelloWorldLayer`.  You would then put the delegate method inside `ScoreLayer.m`:

```
-(void)updateScore:(int)num {
    // Do something
}
```

The way it is now, you declared the protocol in the wrong class.

Comment: I don't think the declaration is in the wrong place, per se. Generally classes who implement a protocol need to know more about it than classes who use it in method signatures. For the latter, we should really be using forward declarations in the headers, and importing in the implementation files. Where to actually define a protocol can be highly subjective, but it need not be so close to a consumer of the protocol.

Comment: And anyways, this has nothing to do with why the delegate isn't receiving the message.